# How to pass a generic type object to a class constructor

Tags: c#, generics, repository, unit-of-work

I have a generic class that will play the repository role, and I have a second class, this second class should receive an object from the generic repository in the constructor.

Generic class (Repository):

```
public sealed class Repo<TContext> : IRepo<TContext>, IDisposable where TContext : DbContext, IDbContextFactory<TContext>, new()
{
    #region properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Private DBContext property
    /// </summary>
    private DbContext _Context { get; } = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Determine if Lazy Loading either activate or not
    /// </summary>
    private bool _LazyLoaded { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Construcors

    public Repo(bool LazyLoaded)
    {
        _Context                                  = new TContext();
        _LazyLoaded                               = LazyLoaded;
        _Context.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = LazyLoaded;
    }

    public Repo(DbContext context,bool LazyLoaded)
    {
        _Context                                  = context;
        _LazyLoaded                               = LazyLoaded;
        _Context.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = LazyLoaded;
    }

    public Repo(IConfiguration configuration, string connectionString,bool LazyLoaded)
    {
        _Context                                  = new TContext().GetInstance(configuration, connectionString);
        _LazyLoaded                               = LazyLoaded;
        _Context.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = LazyLoaded;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**What I tried in my second class :**

```
class UOW:IUOW
{
    public UOW(Repo<DbContext> repo)
    {
        
    }

    public void Commit()
    {

    }

    public void RollBack()
    {

    }
}
```

But I got these two errors:

> CS0311 The type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'Repo'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextFactory<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext>'.

> CS0310 'DbContext' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'Repo'

[image: Screenshot]

How I can configure the constructor of my second class to receive an object from the repo generic class?

Comment: The error is not about constructor per se but the `DbContext` type which seems to be missing empty constructor. And it does not implement `IDbContextFactory`

Comment: any solution or suggestion to fix this issue

Comment: `DbContext` is not a non-abstract type so you cannot use it with the `new()` generic constraint. It also does not implement `IDbContextFactory`

Comment: Declare parameterless constructor and implement `IDbContextFactory`. But for me it seems more to be an example of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want it to have this properties?

Comment: Also, please don't post images of code/error messages, include the actual content in your question in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code, but to take the error you are concerned with here, `DbContext` is not a *non-abstract type* so you cannot use it with the `new()` generic constraint. It also does not implement `IDbContextFactory`. There's a couple of things you can do. First would be to make `UOW` generic and match the same generic constraints, like this:

```
class UOW<TContext> : IUOW
    where TContext : DbContext, IDbContextFactory<TContext>, new()
{
    public UOW(Repo<TContext> repo)
    {
    }
}
```

The second is to use a concrete class that does work with all of those constraints, for example:

```
class MyContext : DbContext, IDbContextFactory<MyContext>
{
    public MyContext CreateDbContext()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class UOW : IUOW
{
    public UOW(Repo<MyContext> repo)
                 // ^^^^^^^^^ Use the new object here
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: But I have a question you said that I have multiple issues with my code, please can you tell me if that you mean the issues about what I asked for, or you meant by issues that I have issues in my classes and their structures problems ? And accept ll my respect sir

Comment: Well that's a different question, for a different site really. However, for a start I wouldn't make a context implement `IDbContextFactory`, that is mixing up things too much and makes far more sense to keep them as separate objects.

Comment: Really I appreciate this for you sir, you are golden man god bless you, after your permission sir can you provide me any of your accounts in social media to contact with you and massive thanks again.